# SKLearn VotingClassifier is throwing an issue about argument not being iterable?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This might seem a bit simplistic and to be honest I have spent a few hours looking at this and trying back and forth and now cannot see the wood from the trees.

I am constantly falling into the same error of a zip argument not being iterable when trying to fit a [dataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and [series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) to a [votingClassifer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.fit).

I currently have the following arrangement:

```py
​def MethodName(Data, Models):
    YColumn = list(Data["target"].values) # Pandas.series = Data["target"]
    XColumn = Data.drop([~ArrayOfColumnsToDrop~],axis=1).to_records() #Pandas.DataFrame =Data[...]
    model = VotingClassifier(estimators=Models, voting='hard')
    model.fit(XColumn, YColumn)
    return(model, score)
```

Currently the following error is returned:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_voting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    322         transformed_y = self.le_.transform(y)
    323 
--> 324         return super().fit(X, transformed_y, sample_weight)
    325 
    326     def predict(self, X):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_voting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
     63     def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
     64         """Get common fit operations."""
---> 65         names, clfs = self._validate_estimators()
     66 
     67         if self.weights is not None and len(self.weights) != len(self.estimators):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_base.py in _validate_estimators(self)
    245                 " of (string, estimator) tuples."
    246             )
--> 247         names, estimators = zip(*self.estimators)
    248         # defined by MetaEstimatorMixin
    249         self._validate_names(names)

TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

My understanding of this is that it wants either the X or Y argument to be iterable and both are:
`

```
 for item in YColumn:
        print(item)
        print("Iterable")
        break
    for item in XColumn:
        print(item)
        print("Iterable")
        break
```

```
0
Iterable
(0, 0.93846872, [...])
Iterable
```

My limited understanding of that would suggest both are iterable arrays; where the YColumn array is a 1d [entry,entry,[...],entry] and the XColumn array is a 1d of [(tuple), (tuple),[...], (tuple)].

Previous attempts:

- Just passing both in as a panda.series and panda.dataFrame respectively
- Having the YColumn be an array of tuples in the format of [(0,Y), (1,Y),...,(D,Y)]. This rightfully complained about not being a simple 1d array
- Using [test_train_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). This resulted in the same error message about the zip iterator as now.

Looking at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.fit) it states that it needs an :

> "X{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)"

could that be the issue? Surely passing the dataFrame in plain is array-like of shape?

What am I missing on this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I am an arrogant coder who is too reliant on following where the error messages are thrown than actually reading them all the way through. Kaggle Notebooks doesn't have a debugger in the IDE sense, but it turns out I can add `%debug` to the start of a [code block](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/83662) and it will provide a traditional debugger.

The issue was not with the `.fit()` method and data types as implied above, but rather I was passing the wrong estimators in. I was passing a list of [estimator1,estimator2,estimator3] when in fact it needed `[("str",estimator1),("str",estimator2),...]`. It even states in the [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html?highlight=voting+classifier#sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier), but I was too fixated on it being a data type issue.

I will now go an think long and hard about how my arrogance and procrastination has lead to me wasting a week. Although in fairness to them, I did decide that if I hadn't got the answer by 19:30 I was going to just write the VotingClassifier myself.

TL:DR: Don't trust the error message and only read the last portion, try and find a debugger, read the damn docs and error message through thoroughly.

**This was solely me being stupid.**